# Method of undetermined coefficients - when do I need to multiply with x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a book that suggests me to use a few classical approaches to solving inhomogenous differential equations, like $y=C*e^{kx}$ for an inhomogeneous part of $i=A*e^{kx}$. If $k$ is a zero of the charakteristic polynomial though, I need to multiply this with t. That said, what if I can not solve the homogeneous with this method, and instead use the separation of variables? How can I then determine if I need to multiply with zero or not?

Comment: @NobleMushtak If k is a multiple zero though, and for a differential equation of fifth order there can be 5 multiple zeroes, then I need to multiple with $x^5$ though. So is using $x^{Order of equation}e{kx}$ a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Sorry, ignore everything I just said. I just messed up and confused variation of parameters with separation of variables for some reason. I actually don't know that much about separation of variables, so you should probably ask someone else for help. Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not every differential equation can be solved with a separation of variables. That being said once you solve the homogeneous equation, you need to avoid any of those solutions to obtain a particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation. Multiplying by a power of t allows for that to happen.

Comment: @JoelPereira That makes sense, but is there a way to know if I need to multiply before I try to solve it? Or will I only notice the need for it once I have tried solving unsucessfully?

Comment: Only after finding the homogeneous solutions is that possible. The question is does the forcing function look like the homogeneous solution.

Comment: Also note that the method of undetermined coefficients only applies to **linear** ODEs, whereas separation of variables is something that you mostly use for (a certain type of) **nonlinear** ODEs.